# What am I doing wrong with this GLM camera rotation?

Tags: opengl, 3d, glm

I'm attempting a very basic camera with GLM in C++ that has full pitch and yaw rotation. The game I'm planning to make will eschew triangles in favor of flat scaled/rotated sprites to represent objects so I only need to know where singular points are located in space.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Called once on init
glm::mat4x4 matProj = glm::perspective(90.0f, (float)ScreenHeight() / (float)ScreenWidth(), 0.1f, 1000.f);
glm::vec3 vUp = { 0.f, 1.f, 0.f };
glm::vec3 cameraFront = { 0.f, 0.f, 1.f };

// ...

// Called when a frame is drawn
glm::mat4x4 matView = glm::lookAt(camera, camera + cameraFront, vUp);
matView = glm::rotate(matView, yaw, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f));
glm::vec3 testPoint(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
glm::mat4 model(1.f);
glm::mat4 mvp = matProj * matView * model;
glm::vec4 testPointProj(testPoint.x, testPoint.y, testPoint.z, 1.f);
testPointProj = testPointProj * mvp;

// testPointProj.x and testPointProj.y are used as the screen (projection) coordinates
```

`testPoint` is supposed to be a point that is directly in front of the camera.
I was under the impression that multiplying `testPointProj` by `mvp` would convert to screen coordinates but when I change `yaw` the point on screen does not move at all. Can anyone help with this? I'm still very new to 3D rendering concepts in general.

Comment: The axis you are rotating around is the axis that extends between the view matrix and the model. My guess is that since you indicate rotational degrees by the variable `yaw`, the vector to yaw around should be 0,1,0 instead of 0,0,1... which is the direction you're looking at. As written, it will remain in place but appear the rotate.

Comment: @SteveH I'd say that's worth posting as an answer below.

Comment: @SteveH I tried replacing 0,0,1 with 0,1,0 in glm::rotate but the point still does not move. I should also note that I am using testPointProj.x and testPointProj.y as the screen coordinates. I'll edit the question to show that.